# get intro-image from article?

Tags: joomla-api, images

I do not get the images out of my article. The article var is initialized, but the images and pictures vars seem to be empty. Any hints what I do wrong here?

```
<?php
   $id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id');
   $article = JTable::getInstance("content");
   $article->load($id);
   $images = $article->item->images;
   echo $images;
   $pictures = json_decode($images);
   echo $pictures;
?>

<?php echo $pictures->image_intro; ?>
```

Comment: So what, of the above, is being printed to screen? Which lines is generating a warning/notice/error?

Comment: Is the code part of template override, module or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When developing, error reporting should be enabled. You'll see this:

> Notice: Undefined property: Joomla\CMS\Table\Content::$item

Access the images like this:

```
$images = $article->images;
```

Comment: "When developing, error reporting should be enabled." - This is more useful advise than the corrected piece of code below it ;)