# How to include images in Joomla's search results?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, search, images, com-search

I'm trying to display images in search results for the default search of Joomla.
I messed with some code from the web and I managed to display images with the following:

in template/html/com_search/com_search/search/default_results.php:

in line 9, I added:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$article = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable');
```

---

and then above:

```
<dd class="result-text">  <?php echo $result->text;?></dd>
```

I added:

```
<?php   
// Joomla content
if( strstr($result->href, 'com_content') ) 
{
    preg_match_all('#\d+#', $result->href, $val);
    $id = (int)$val[0][0];
    $article->load($id);            
}
?>

<?php
$dom = new DOMDOcument;
$dom->loadHTML($article->introtext);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
if (isset($images[0])) {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $images[0]->getAttribute('src'); ?>" class="search-results-img">
    <?php 
}
?>
```

The result is images in search results with image class for styling in css, BUT it works only for article search. If search includes categories too, I get:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input.

I think the warning is because of `$dom->loadHTML($article->introtext);`

I want someone to check the code as I think using `preg_match_all()` isn't the best practice and I need to include categories image.

Comment: I would like to post an educational answer.  Can you please provide a sample `$result->href` value so that I can tailor my answer to your question and data?  Also, what kind of incoming data do you receive when processing a category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers to offer:

When checking the existence of a substring in a string, the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) advises:

> Note:
>
> If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.

So it is best practice to use `if (strpos($result->href, 'com_content') !== false) {`

As for extracting the numeric substring, you *could* entertain a call of `filter_var()`:

```
$id = (int)filter_var($result->href, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

However, your case is a great opportunity to perform validation and extraction at the same time with a `preg_` function call.

Because you only intend to make a single match, simply use `preg_match()` instead of `preg_match_all()`.  I can help you with this dual-purpose pattern, using your supplied value of:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=14623:vw-tiguan-allspace-geneva-2017&catid=136
```

I have a penchant for using `\K` to restart the fullstring match instead of using capture groups.  This is a micro-optimisation that reduces the regex engine's "step" count and this also eliminates unnecessary output array bloat (in `$match`  ...see my snippet below).

To prevent the warning from the DOMDocument line, you should encapsulate that portion of your script inside your condition block as well.  If you need to provide a fallback value for categories, that will go in your `else` condition block.  Alternatively, you can just wrap your DOM parsing code in a condition that checks if `$article->introtext` isset().  `if (isset($article->introtext)) { ... }`

This is my general (untested) recommendation:

```
$imageSrc = '';
if (preg_match('~index\.php\?option=com_content&view=article&id=\K\d+~', $result->href, $match)) {
    //validation ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^--- extraction
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $article = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable');
    $article->load((int)$match[0]);

    if (isset($article->introtext)) {
        $dom = new DOMDOcument;
        $dom->loadHTML($article->introtext);
        $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        if (isset($images[0])) {
            $imageSrc = $images[0]->getAttribute('src');
        }
    }
}
```

When you want to use `$imageSrc`...

```
if ($imageSrc) {
    echo "<img src=\"{$imageSrc}\" class=\"search-results-img\" alt=\"\">";
}
```

---

Again this is untested, but based on [another snippets I found](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/10896/12352), this might be a better way of pulling the article image:

```
if (isset($article->images)) {
    $images = json_decode($article->images);
    if (isset($images->image_intro, $images->image_intro_alt)) {
        echo "<img class=\"image_intro\" src=\"{$images->image_intro}\" alt=\"{$images->image_intro_alt}\">";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `$result->href` returns article url (index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=14623:vw-tiguan-allspace-geneva-2017&catid=136). For categories: i have categories like vw videos, vw offers etc. When i search "vw" it returns the 2 categories and next it returns all articless about vw. Your recommendation above, returns `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input`. Categories is not important to have image, but articles are.

Comment: Adding `if (isset($article->introtext)){ ` before `$dom->loadHTML($article->introtext);` eleminates the warning, but in both cases (warning and no warning) no image is showing

Comment: I've updated my snippet.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. Using your updated snippet no image is showing. However putting `echo "<img src=\"{$imageSrc}\" class=\"search-results-img\" alt=\"\">";` before last `}` or using `<?php echo "<img src=\"{$imageSrc}\" class=\"search-results-img\" alt=\"\">";?>` results empty image. Inspecting empty image it returns base url (/joomla3-7/).

Comment: I don't have access to my Joomla projects because I am only on my phone.  If you can show me what attributes the `<img>` tags hold and the desired `$imageSrc` value, then I can connect the dots.  You said your snippet was partially working so I based my answer on your snippet.  Do you actually want this?  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/24625/12352 ...or see the syntax here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/25141/12352 If my updated answer doesn't help, please tell me what data an article object holds for you.

Comment: In your snippet, i changed `if (preg_match('~index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=\K\d+~', $result->href, $match))` with `if (preg_match('#\d+#', $result->href, $match))` and it worked. Thank you ve ry much for your time and efforts. Once again you helped me.

Comment: Sorry, my answer had the rookie mistake of not escaping characters with special meaning.  I have escaped the `.` and `?` to make them literal matches.  This should perform the validation properly now.

Comment: Yes that works without any changes, Thanks again.